# How to insert formula if cell in row below contains a date?

Tags: excel, vba

Edited for more info

I run a report which can start and finish from any dates (e.g. 1 May to 31 May). It plots the dates across the top row, breaking up weeks with two rows of calculations. So if I ran the report from 1 May (a Friday), across the top row it would have 3 dates (Fri-Sun), then two rows of information, then 7 dates, two rows of information etc.

I want to insert a macro that will insert a formula above any cell in this row which contains a date. I don't know how to insert something based on the formatting of another cell.

This is the top row of the sheet:

[image]

I could insert a formula (e.g. =IF(Q2=0,"",FORMULA)) and then convert to text. I've  tried various combinations of the "IF" thing to see if I can get it to only action the formula if the cell contains a number, but I can't make that work either.

I could change the formatting of the dates as follows:

`Range("Z1:AF1").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm (ddd)"
Range("AI1:AO1").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm (ddd)"
Range("AR1:AX1").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm (ddd)"
Range("BA1:BF1").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm (ddd)"`

etc.

And run the formula if it contains "(Mon)" or "(Tue)" etc. But this only works if I've hard-coded the specific cells I want it to use, which means I can't run the report for any range of dates.

None of these are particularly agile, and seem to be working around an issue which seems that it would be quite simple (inserting the formula based on the formatting of the cell below it). But none of my Googling has brought up anything that suggests this is possible.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a screenshot and explain what your code would do on that screenshot. Also please show what you already have tried and add that code to your question. People asking for help should have researched and tried something before (see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))

Comment: Maybe, **in VBA**:  `If IsDate([Q2]) then X else Y`